# Laravel ->when() with greater than or lesser than

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to run different ->where() condition based to id.

Example what I'm trying to do:

I have joined activity table to interests table and based to ID I'd like to run different where condition.

```
 ->when('activity.id' <= '214469112', function ($q) {
    return $q->where('interests.type', 'regular');
       }, function ($q) {
       return $q->where('activity.main', 1);
       })->get();
```

However ->when() does not seem to respect <= => greater than or less than and returns always false so the  `return $q->where('activity.main', 1);` is always used.

Any ideas how I could achieve different ->where() condition based to greater or less than with activity.id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sigh, sometimes one just tries to overcomplicate the problem.

Did this by using:

`Where('id', '>', int)->where('condition1')->orWhere('id', '<=', int)->where('condition2')->get();`

Comment: there is no =< operator in php, it must be <=

Answer (score 4):

Laravel's `->when()` method needs the first parameter to be true to run the first callback.

In the docs they determine the value of `$role` beforehand then pass it to the `when()` method.

```
` $role = $request->input('role');

  $users = DB::table('users')
            ->when($role, function ($query) use ($role) {
                return $query->where('role_id', $role);
            })
            ->get(); `
```

You are trying to pass through a SQL expression as if it were a `where` clause which its not.
If you evaluate `'activity.id' <= '214469112'` in artisan tinker it will return `false` which explains why the second callback is always being run.

In other words you are comparing a string (`'activity.id'`) with a string (`'214469112'`) which is the issue here.

I hope this helps!

Comment: While I solved it the other way (my answer in the question) this was extremely useful info for the future, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be useful for someone. If you need to group an "**or**", "**and**" condition with "**when()**". if *$request->phone* true: ...*and (('from' like '%phone%') or ('to' like '%phone%'))*

```
->when($request->phone, function ($query, $phone) {
      return $query->where(function($query) use ($phone) {
             $query->where('from', 'like', "%$phone%")->orWhere('to', 'like', "%$phone%");
                    });
```