# How does the "when" statement work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say, there is a code like this

```
$users = Model::when($param, function($query) {
        $query->where('id', 1)
    })
    ->get();
```

the "when" function, if the `$param` parameter is present, will call the function and the query will be

```
select * from table where id = 1
```

If there is no parameter, then the query will be

```
select * from table
```

The question is how and where Laravel collects this dynamic request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57128668/5947043

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/post/less-know-way-conditional-queries

Comment: If those don't help, can you please clarify the question and be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. Are you asking what causes the callback function to be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, just go to the source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6316655d0bc823854aa3397d2f21515a5eb03929/src/Illuminate/Conditionable/Traits/Conditionable.php#L21-L40

It is a trait called `Conditionable` (`\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Conditionable`):

```
public function when($value = null, callable $callback = null, callable $default = null)
{
    $value = $value instanceof Closure ? $value($this) : $value;

    if (func_num_args() === 0) {
        return new HigherOrderWhenProxy($this);
    }

    if (func_num_args() === 1) {
        return (new HigherOrderWhenProxy($this))->condition($value);
    }

    if ($value) {
        return $callback($this, $value) ?? $this;
    } elseif ($default) {
        return $default($this, $value) ?? $this;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This is for Laravel 10.x

---

Because the method `when` returns `$this` (at the last line), it allows you to do `$model->when(..., ...)->when(..., ...)->where(xxx)->first()` (as an example). That is called [`method chaining`](https://programmingdive.com/how-to-use-method-chaining-in-php/) when you *chain* method calls like that example.

Comment: Probably key to OP's understanding is that `return $this` enables what's known as "method chaining", which is heavily used by Laravel's query builder.

Comment: @ceejayoz good catch! I will update it

Comment: @matiaslauriti It seems to me that the question is exactly how Laravel substitutes the condition -> where (). 
In pure PHP, you would have to write if the parameter exists, then $pdo->prepare("select from table where column = : column"); If it doesn't exist then $pdo->prepare("select from table");

Comment: @KordDEM and the answer is literally in the code

Comment: @matiaslauriti I just made it clear =)